# Using SQL statement to add data to EF db

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(User user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO dbo.Users VALUES (" + user.ToString() + ")";
            db.Database.SqlQuery<User>(sqlQuery);
            db.SaveChanges();

            Session["User"] = user.UserName;
            Session["Pass"] = user.Password;
            Session["RoleID"] = user.RoleID;

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Shop");
        }

        return View(user);
    }
```

Everything in this action works besides the sqlQuery part, I got no errors during run-time or compilation.

The data simply not being added to the Database table.

The ToString() Simply return all the props with commas between each other:

```
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Orders = new HashSet<Order>();
    }

    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int RoleID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "'" + this.UserID + "','" + this.UserName + "','" + this.Password 
            + "','" + this.Name + "','" + this.Email + "','" + this.Address + "','" + this.RoleID + "'";
    }
}
```

Table Data Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users]
(
    [UserID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    [UserName] TEXT NOT NULL, 
    [Password] TEXT NOT NULL, 
    [Name] TEXT NOT NULL, 
    [Email] TEXT NOT NULL, 
    [Address] TEXT NOT NULL, 
    [RoleID] INT NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Users_Roles] FOREIGN KEY ([RoleID]) REFERENCES [Roles]     ([RoleID])
)
```

---

**Solved**

I have recreated the database using SQL Server Express and I was making sure that the ID field will be auto-increment.
Regenerated the database using ADO.NET Entity DB... changed names in code, and Now everything works !

Comment: Post your code not a picture of your code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems **UserID** is auto-increment property, so remove **this.UserID** from ToSring() method. And also, as you don't need UserID remove this `if(!db.Users.Any()) user.UserID=0` of the controller.

Actually, **SqlQuery** method is used for **Select** query whereas **ExecuteSqlCommnad** method is useful for **Insert**, **Update** or **Delete** command.

So, Replace **SqlQuery** with **ExecuteSqlCommnad**, it will insert data to the table.

**Update**

I create table as you add in the question and added following code in the controller. It insert data to the table without any issues.

**Controller**

```
var user = "'" + "Admin" + 
           "', '" + "123456" + 
           "', '" + "Local Host" +
           "', '" + "admin@admin.com" +
           "', '" + "Local, Host st" +
           "', '" + "1" + "'";

var query = "INSERT INTO Users VALUES (" + user + ")";

var context = new YourDbContext();
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(query);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: The data still not being insert into the table

Comment: tried it, After replace it I got an error that said the number of columns i'm trying to insert isn't matching the table(probably because of the `UserID`), so I added the `UserID`, and after that I'm keep getting this error: `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: String or binary data would be truncated.`. From what I have seen it's says that the data I'm trying to insert isn't matching the Type of the column or not long enough, so I changed everything to `Text` instead of `nchar(10)`, but still with no success

Comment: @kingston951, will u show me the structure the table? [Take a screenshot of your table structure with data type, upload it anywhere and paste the URL here]

Comment: @kingston951, As per your Table  Structure, Remove UserID from insert query and use ExecuteSqlCommnad, If it still not help you, then change DataType text to varchar(MAX).

Comment: Tried both your solution and none worked. still getting the error I mentioned above.

Comment: Then will u give me the data you try to insert?

Comment: I have another idea, maybe I can create a store procedure that takes the user props as parameters and then add it to the table, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to put a breakpoint in your code before executing the `Database.SqlQuery<User>(sqlQuery);` statement and inspect whether you have a correct SQL insert statement. When the breakpoint hits, Copy the value of `sqlQuery` varaiable (which has your insert statement) and try to execute that directly on a SSMS query window. If that is successfully inserting one record, that means your query is fine.

I could see a problem in your query. Your `RoleID` column is of type **int**, but in your `toString()` implementation you are wrapping it inside single quotes as you are dealing with a string field.

```
+ "','" + this.RoleID + "'"
```

As i said above, Capture the value of sqlQuery variable and it will tell you what is wrong.

**EDIT** : *As per the comment of OP*

Your User table has a UserID column and i do not see that in your Insert statement. If the column is set to get Auto Increment/Identity values, Other than the UserID column, you have only 6 columns. But your Insert statement has 7 values.

You should try the below one. Here i am specifying what columns i want to insert into. You can notice that the number of columns and number of values i pass match

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Users (UserName,Password,Name,Email,Address,RoleID) 
 VALUES 
('someUserName','pass','Scott','localhost@local.com','My addrss',0)
```

Also make sure that If `RoleId` has a forigen key to the Role table, you should be passing a valid `RoleId` instead of 0.

Carefully evaluate your sql statement to make sure that you have proper single quotes closing for every single quotes you opened for string values.

Comment: This is the statement I'm getting and it's really not working as query `INSERT INTO dbo.Users VALUES ('Testing123','123456','LocalHost','localhost@local.com','Local , Host st',0)` I can't understand what's wrong in this statement.

Comment: I have tried the statement you wrote, and I notice that I really don't have RoleID-0, So I changed it to 5(Customer) and then I got this error, like the one I wrote in the second answer: `Msg 8152, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.`